# Add type of newsletter in the email subject of Stack Overflow newsletter

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

It would be good if the subject of the email contains what type of newsletter i.e Mathematics, Programming, etc,. It helps us moving the newsletter automatically to a folder when using email client.

Answer (score 2):

It already does for me...

[image: mail client screenshot]